# Laravel - How to get last 5 dates from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have a model `ImportantDate` the schema is as below

```
Schema::create('important_dates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->date('date');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

I want to get:

1) last five dates from current date (today) and

2) next five days from current date (today)

Sample Data:

```
id    Date          description
1     2017-12-20    some description
2     2017-12-25    some description
3     2018-01-02    some description
4     2018-01-28    some description
5     2018-02-02    some description
6     2018-02-12    some description
7     2018-02-18    some description
8     2018-02-28    some description
9     2018-03-02    some description
10    2018-03-12    some description
```

In my `ImportantDatesController.php` i have tried a query which displays recent dates from current date but i need last 5 dates and next 5 dates from today.

```
public function index() 
{
    $upcoming_dates = ImportantDate::orderByRaw(' abs( timestampdiff(second, current_timestamp, created_at)) asc ')
                                    ->limit(5)
                                    ->get();

    $recent_dates = ImportantDate::orderByRaw(' abs( timestampdiff(second, current_timestamp, created_at)) dsc ')
                                    ->limit(5)
                                    ->get();

    return view('pages.dashboard', compact('upcoming_dates','recent_dates'));
}
```

Looking forward for much needed help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `where()` clause to `compare` your date is an `upcoming` date or `previous` date. Then you can use `orderBy()` to get the latest 5 according to your dates.

```
$upcoming_dates = ImportantDate::where('date','>', date('Y-m-d'))->orderBy('date')
                                ->limit(5)
                                ->get();

$recent_dates = ImportantDate::where('date','<', date('Y-m-d'))->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
                                ->limit(5)
                                ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATE('Y-m-d')` will gives a current date in given format. if you need to get current date top, can use add `>=` or `<=`

```
$upcoming_dates = ImportantDate::where('date' , '>', DATE('Y-m-d'))
                    ->orderBy('id', asc)
                    ->limit(5)
                    ->get();

$recent_dates = ImportantDate::where('date', '<', DATE('Y-m-d'))
                    ->orderBy('id', desc)
                    ->limit(5)
                    ->get();
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE datetime = (SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM table))
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time, this RAW query might help other.